# How to avoid 'Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK' error across methods

Tags: mysql, django, transactions

I have a situation where I have applied the @transaction.commit_manually decorator to a method in which I am importing information passed back in an http request response.  I need to control committing and rolling back depending on whether business validation rules pass or fail.

Now, when I have some sort of validation failure I have a separate method in which I log an error to the database.  This action should always commit immediately, while leaving the primary transaction in its current state.  However, what happens is if I apply the @transaction.commit_on_success decorator to the error capturing routine, my primary transaction commits automatically as well.  If I don't apply the @transaction.commit_on_success decorator, then, I receive the 'Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK' error as soon as a call is made to the error capturing routine.

I am using MYSQL database version 5.1.49 using storage engine INNODB.

Is there a way to persist the open transaction in the calling routine while committing the transaction in the second routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's default transaction management doesn't support nested transactions. In general, transactions *can't* be nested. Everything that's done in the midst of a transaction is either committed or rolledback. So when you commit the transaction, no matter where you commit the transaction, it's atomic.

Looking around online, I found a [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2515/) that might be a good starting point for you. It essentially overrides the `commit_on_success` decorator, adding a form of reference counting. In a sense, it forgoes committing if it's not the last out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have been happy with the Django framework thus far (this is my first experience with it), however, the lack of flexility in managing database transactions seems to be a shortcoming to me in light of what I was able to do using the .NET framework.  At the very least it seems that a single "transaction" object should be able to be passed to different classes or methods.

Comment: Have you looked at savepoints? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Yes, but, according to the docs, and verified through my own testing, it does not appear that savepoints work with the MySQL INNODB database (at least under Django 1.2.5)